# Impute values in grouped data by condition in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I like to impute a variable in grouped paneldata with `tidyverse` logic. The story is this: It is survey data and people are asked in particular years (time) for a behavior in the last couple of years. Thus I assume when someone said "I had a car for 5 years", that the car variable in those years can set to be 1. The question was not asked in those years. This is minimal data and the imputation I like to achieve.

```
paneldata = data.frame(id=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10)), 
                       time=seq(1:10), 
                       car=c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1),
                       car_imp_goal=c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
paneldata
```

Here is what I tried

```
paneldata <- paneldata %>% mutate(car_imp_trial = car) 
paneldata %>% group_by(id) %>% fill(car_imp_trial , .direction = "up")


# A tibble: 20 × 5
# Groups:   id [2]
      id  time   car car_imp_goal car_imp_trial 
   <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     1     1     1       1        1
 2     1     2    NA      NA        0
 3     1     3    NA      NA        0
 4     1     4    NA      NA        0
 5     1     5    NA      NA        0
 6     1     6     0       0        0
 7     1     7    NA       1        1
 8     1     8    NA       1        1
 9     1     9    NA       1        1
10     1    10     1       1        1
11     2     1     1       1        1
12     2     2    NA       1        1
13     2     3    NA       1        1
14     2     4    NA       1        1
15     2     5     1       1        1
16     2     6    NA       1        1
17     2     7    NA       1        1
18     2     8    NA       1        1
19     2     9    NA       1        1
20     2    10     1       1        1
```

The past behavior question is only asked in specificy years (e.g. time 5 and 10). I need to `group_by(id)` then use `ifelse` condition to select relevant time, i.e. 5 or 10 then was thinking about using `fill`. What is wrong about `car_imp_trial`  is that it filled 0 from year 6, which is not a pasted behaviour question.

Comment: what result do you want? `car_imp`column?

Comment: How do you know its 5 years? 4years? etc. or is it just when we see a 0?

Comment: It is exactly at time 5 and 10. There might be more values in between. And there are time points completly missing. While an answer at time 5 is true for the last 5 years, sometimes I only have 2 years (with gaps).

Comment: Id 1 has no answer at time 5. They have an answer at time 6 and 10. should time 7 be 0?

Comment: When there is nothing for ID at time 5, nothing can be imputed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a time interval id, then fill upwards the car column

```
paneldata%>%
   group_by(id,id2 = cut_interval(time, length = 5,labels =FALSE))%>%
   fill(car, .direction = 'up')

# A tibble: 20 × 5
# Groups:   id, id2 [4]
      id  time   car car_imp   id2
   <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
 1     1     1     1       1     1
 2     1     2    NA      NA     1
 3     1     3    NA      NA     1
 4     1     4    NA      NA     1
 5     1     5    NA      NA     1
 6     1     6     0       0     2
 7     1     7     1       1     2
 8     1     8     1       1     2
 9     1     9     1       1     2
10     1    10     1       1     2
11     2     1     1       1     1
12     2     2     1       1     1
13     2     3     1       1     1
14     2     4     1       1     1
15     2     5     1       1     1
16     2     6     1       1     2
17     2     7     1       1     2
18     2     8     1       1     2
19     2     9     1       1     2
20     2    10     1       1     2
```